# ¿Cómo leer un archivo de texto en un Fragment Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, archivo

resulta que intento leer un archivo de texto desde un *fragment* pero al momento de abrirlo en la aplicación me salta que la aplicación dejó de funcionar, así que quería saber si me podían dar una mano.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vocabulary,container);
    TextView voc=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vocabulario);
    try {


        InputStream archivo=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.leccion10);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(archivo));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String linea;
        while((linea =bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
            stringBuilder.append(linea).append("\n");
        }
        voc.setText(stringBuilder);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return view;
}
```

Trate de encontrar la solución pero ya me quede sin ideas, espero su ayuda, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, cual es el error desplegado en el LogCat?, definiste permisost? que sistema operativo usas?. te sugiero revises [ask] , debes aportar detalles que ayuden a solucionar tu pregunta, en el caso de Android es indispensable el uso del LogCat

Comment: Buenas tardes, mas a detalle uso windows 10 , y el problema surge de la siguiente forma:
Entro a la aplicación y la activity es una bottomNavigationActivity, tengo 4 pestañas, y cuando entro la que tiene que leer el archivo me salta que la aplicación a dejado de funcionar, en el logcat no me salta nada.

Comment: Agrega tu logcat

Answer (score 0):

```
setTitle("Vocabulario");
                VocabularyFragment vocab = new VocabularyFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.fram, vocab,"Fragment_vocabulary");
                fragmentTransaction2.commit();
                return true;
```

Este bloque de codigo es para entrar al fragment que se llama VocabularyFragment.
Luego en el fragment_vocabulary.xml tengo lo siguiente:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vocab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
```

Y finalmente en el VocabularyFragment.java en el metodo onCreateView tengo lo siguiente:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vocabulary,container);
    TextView vocab= view.findViewById(R.id.vocab);
    try {
        leer(vocab);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return view;
}
```

y el metodo leer es un metodo void que tiene lo siguiente:

```
public void leer(TextView vocab)throws IOException{
    try {

        InputStream archivo=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.vocabulario);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(archivo));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String linea;
        while((linea =bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
            stringBuilder.append(linea).append("\n");
        }
        vocab.setText(stringBuilder);
        archivo.close();
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

**El código para obtener el contenido del archivo es correcto**, simplemente asegura tengas el archivo `/raw/leccion1.txt`

```
InputStream archivo=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.leccion1);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(archivo));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String linea;
        while((linea =bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
            stringBuilder.append(linea).append("\n");
        }
```

No veo que realices la captura de `NullPointerException` por lo tanto me parece que el error se encuentra aquí:

```
  voc.setText(stringBuilder);
```

El debes asegurar que el `TextView` llamado `voc` , en realidad se encuentre dentro del layout `fragment_vocabulary.xml` :

```
  view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vocabulary,container);
    TextView voc=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vocabulario);
```

si no se encuentra, la instancia del `TextView` tendrá un valor Null

Comment: Amigo justamente revise eso creyendo que era ese el problema pero mira te dejo a detalle el codigo porque ya revise y tengo creado el textview con ese nombre e incluso lo intente por medio de funciones, lo dejo en la siguiente respuesta

Comment: Hola Diego, es importante revisar el LogCat ahí debe mostrarse el detalle del error.