# Al leer un archivo se cierra mi aplicación android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, archivo

llevo un largo rato intentando solucionar un problema que estoy teniendo al momento de querer leer un archivo en android. Quisiera que alguien me ayude a darme cuenta el error:
esto vendria a ser la parte del onCreate de mi activity que vendria a llamarse Lesson1Activity.java

```
TextView texto;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lesson1);
    try {
        leer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

luego esta la parte de la lectura que viene a ser el método leer():

```
public void leer() throws IOException{
    try {

        InputStream archivo=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.leccion1);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(archivo));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String linea;
        while((linea =bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
            stringBuilder.append(linea).append("\n");
        }
        texto.setText(stringBuilder);
        archivo.close();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

El problema esta en que al momento de entrar a esta activity mi aplicación se cierra y en el logcat no me figura ningun error.
Si alguien sabe cual es el error que esta causando esto, porfavor pido que me lo explique detalladamente para evitar confusiones. Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Esta pregunta la realizaste anteriormente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130141/como-leer-un-archivo-de-texto-en-un-fragment-android-studio , revisar [ask]

Answer (score -1):

Tu variable TextView es null, en ningun momento la estas instanciando ya sea mediante el constructor o cargandola desde el layout de la actividad usando findViewById().

Debes modificar el método onCreate Implementando una de las dos formas para instanciarlo, el código funcionaría y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

**onCreate**

```
TextView texto;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lesson1);

    texto = new TextView(this); //Primera forma
    texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_de_tu_textview); //Segunda forma

    try {
        leer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Si has instanciado el `TextView` mediante el constructor, debes añadirlo al layout en el método leer():

**método leer()**

```
public void leer() throws IOException{
    try {

        InputStream archivo=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.leccion1);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(archivo));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String linea;
        while((linea =bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
            stringBuilder.append(linea).append("\n");
        }
        texto.setText(stringBuilder);
        ((tipo de layout) findViewById(R.id.id_del_layout)).addView(texto); //<-- linea que debes añadir si instancias mediante constructor
        archivo.close();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Si el `TextView` lo cargas con `findViewById` entonces la linea que te he añadido en el método leer() la borras y usas tu método leer original.